# ARM M4 blinky error

Tags: c, arm, keil, cortex-m, m4

I'm new to ARM and Keil software. I have experience in assembler with the 8051 series but this is a whole new thing for me.
I bought an XMC4200 application board and was able to use the blinky script and understand the script.
Now i'm making my own blinky example from scratch.
The code is identically to the first blinky.
When i compile the code i receive this error message:

> C:\Keil_v5\ARM\PACK\ARM\CMSIS\5.3.0\CMSIS\Include\arm_math.h(341):
>   error: #35: #error directive: "Define according the used Cortex core
>   ARM_MATH_CM7, ARM_MATH_CM4, ARM_MATH_CM3, ARM_MATH_CM0PLUS,
>   ARM_MATH_CM0, ARM_MATH_ARMV8MBL, ARM_MATH_ARMV8MML" #error "Define
>   according the used Cortex core ARM_MATH_CM7, ARM_MATH_CM4,
>   ARM_MATH_CM3, ARM_MATH_CM0PLUS, ARM_MATH_CM0, ARM_MATH_ARMV8MBL,
>   ARM_MATH_ARMV8MML"

I have no idea why this error happened and how to solve it. Could somebody help me with this please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems that you have to specify the specific ARM core of your board. Check on the samples that comes with the board. You should put a `#define <one of that symbols>` as first line in each source file. I suppose that the correct one for a CORTEX 4200 is `#define ARM_MATH_CM4`.

Comment: Use `-D<your target ARM core>` in your  compiler switches.
You may be able to do it in the project properties in the Kiel IDE.

Comment: It indeed tried to define ARM_MATH_CM4. No result, after a good look at my example. I found out i had a CMSIS library extra than the example. Deleting this library solved the problem. For now...

Comment: When creating a new project in uVision, you specify the target in order to have access to an SVD (system view description) file. That file contains the information needed so that the IDE can define the correct set of processor symbols. Is that the way in which you created this project?